# fast sorting algorithm for multiple ordered arrays

Tags: clojure

I have 4 arrays, that are ordered. I'd like to be able to combine them together into a single sorted datastructure and lazily take from that.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

```
[1 3 4 6 9 10 15]
[2 3 6 7 8 9 10]
[1 3 6 7 8 9 10]
[1 2 3 4 8 9 10]

=> [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4]
```

Comment: I thought I could find an easy answer, but I couldn't.  Most efficient would some kind of merge sort, I think. May have to hand code it using `loop/recur` (or plain Java for max speed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure comes with a library of functions producing or operating on lazy sequences, such as `map`, `iterate` and `take-while`. I believe a merge algorithm could be expressed by combining them, something like this.

```
(defn insert-into-sorted [dst x]
  (let [x0 (first x)
        a (take-while #(< (first %) x0) dst)
        b (drop (count a) dst)]
    (vec (concat a [x] b))))

(defn next-arrays [arrs]
  (let [[f & r] arrs
        restf (rest f)]
    (if (empty? restf)
      r
      (insert-into-sorted r restf))))

(defn merge-sorted-arrays [arrs]
  (->> arrs
       (filter seq)
       (sort-by first)
       (iterate next-arrays)
       (take-while seq)
       (map ffirst)))
```

And we can call it like this:

```
(merge-sorted-arrays [[1 3 4 6 9 10 15]
                      [2 3 6 7 8 9 10]
                      [1 3 6 7 8 9 10]
                      [1 2 3 4 8 9 10]])
;; => (1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 6 6 6 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 15)
```

It is true that you could do something like `(sort (apply concat ...))` but that could turn out inefficient if you have a lot of data.

**Update**: A previous version of this code contained a call to `count` that limited its applicability to merging sequences of *finite* length. By changing it to using `empty?` instead, there is no such limitation and we can now use it to merge sequences of *infinite* length:

```
(take 12 (merge-sorted-arrays [(iterate (partial + 1.1) 1) (iterate (partial + 1.11) 1)]))
;; => (1 1 2.1 2.1100000000000003 3.2 3.2200000000000006 4.300000000000001 4.330000000000001 5.4 5.440000000000001 6.5 6.550000000000002)
```

Comment: I'm still staring at the code trying to figure out how it works. Thanks heaps.

Comment: You're welcome! The most important function is arguably `iterate`, used to express iterative algorithms and produce a sequence of iterated values. It is useful in many situations where you would otherwise use `loop`. In our case, the iterated value are the arrays sorted by their first element.

Comment: I just discovered a bug that limited its use to *finite* sequences. See the modified answer above with an example on sequences of infinite length.

Comment: i did get a stackoverflow at about 10000 items. I'll try again with this approach.

Comment: I'm still getting the stackoverflow. It happened at around 25000 elements :  at clojure.core$concat$cat__5217$fn__5218.invoke(core.clj:726)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)

Comment: The counts of the arrays are as follows: (4954 4712 4708 4703 4699 3718 2634 2627)

Comment: I managed to reproduce this. The problem is that concatenate is lazy (see https://stuartsierra.com/2015/04/26/clojure-donts-concat). One way to fix it is to apply `vec` to it just after concatenation to remove the laziness, that is `(vec (concat a [x] b))`. Or you can do `(reduce into [] [a [x] b])`. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217523/discussion-between-zcaudate-and-rulle).

Comment: For the computation of `a` and `b` in `insert-into-sorted` we can write `[a b] (split-with #(< (first %) x0) dst)`.

Answer (score 3):

there is also a nice way to do it by just counting items' frequencies into sorted map, and then unwrapping it with `repeat`:

```
(def data [[1 3 4 6 9 10 15]
           [2 3 6 7 8 9 10]
           [1 3 6 7 8 9 10]
           [1 2 3 4 8 9 10]])

(->> data
     (apply concat)
     (reduce #(update %1 %2 (fnil inc 0)) (sorted-map))
     (mapcat (fn [[k v]] (repeat v k))))

;;=> (1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 6 6 6 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 15)
```

also there is a less hacky approach:

```
(defn min-first-idx [data]
  (when-let [items (->> data
                        (keep-indexed (fn [i x] (when (seq x) [x i])))
                        seq)]    
    (second (apply min-key ffirst items))))

(defn min-and-more [data-v]
  (when-let [i (min-first-idx data-v)]
    [(first (data-v i)) (update data-v i rest)]))

user> (min-and-more [[1 2 3] [0 1 4] [4 5]])
;; [0 [[1 2 3] (1 4) [4 5]]]
```

so you use it to iteratively take smallest item and rest from collection:

```
(->> [nil (vec data)]      
     (iterate (comp min-and-more second))
     rest
     (take-while (comp seq second))
     (map first))

;; (1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 6 6 6 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 15)
```

Answer (score 2):

I slightly modified Rulle's answer to provide sorting on maps:

```
(defn sort-arrays-insert
  ([key dst x]
   (let [x0 ( key (first x))
         a  (take-while #(< (key (first %)) x0) dst)
         b  (drop (count a) dst)]
     (concat a [x] b))))

(defn sort-arrays-next
  ([key arrs]
   (let [[f & r] arrs]
     (if (<= (count f) 1)
       r
       (sort-arrays-insert key r (rest f))))))

(defn sort-arrays
  ([key arr0 arr1 & more]
   (->> (apply list arr0 arr1 more)
        (filter seq)
        (sort-by (comp key first))
        (iterate #(sort-arrays-next key %))
        (take-while seq)
        (map ffirst))))
```

```
(sort-arrays identity
             [1 3 4 6 9 10 15]
             [2 3 6 7 8 9 10]
             [1 3 6 7 8 9 10]
             [1 2 3 4 8 9 10])

=> (1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 6 6 6 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 15)
```

```
(sort-arrays :time
             [{:time 1} {:time 4}]
             [{:time 2} {:time 3}]
             [{:time 3} {:time 5} {:time 7}]
             [{:time 1} {:time 10}])

=> ({:time 1} {:time 1} {:time 2} {:time 3} {:time 3} {:time 4} {:time 5} {:time 7} {:time 10})
```

Also doing some benchmarking on Rulle, Peter and Leetwinski's answers, I found that Peter's answer is about twice as fast as the rest:

```
(let [L 20000
        N 10]
    (mapv (fn [f]
            (let [arrs (vec (for [i (range N)]
                              (vec (range L))))]
              (time (doall (f arrs)))))
          [merge-sorted       ;; Rulle's
           merge-sorted-2     ;; Peter's
           merge-sorted-3     ;; Leetwinski's
]))


"Elapsed time: 721.649222 msecs"  ;; Rulle's
"Elapsed time: 373.058068 msecs"  ;; Peter's
"Elapsed time: 754.717533 msecs"  ;; Leetwinski's
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Rulle's solution and leetwinski's second one use `iterate` in quite an [anamorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism) manner (especially the latter). Let's define `unfold` using `iterate` (usually the opposite is done) and write an explicitly anamorphic solution:

```
(defn unfold [f s]
  (->> s
       (list nil)
       (iterate (comp f second))
       rest
       (take-while some?)
       (map first)))

(defn merge-sorted [s]
  (->> s
       (filter seq)
       (unfold
         (fn [s]
           (if (seq s)
             (loop [[[mf & mn :as m] & s] s, r ()]
               (if-let [[[xf :as x] & s] s]
                 (let [[m x] (if (< xf mf) [x m] [m x])]
                   (recur (cons m s) (cons x r)))
                 (list mf (if mn (cons mn r) r)))))))))
```

---

## UPDATE

Here is a version of `merge-sorted` that uses `reduce` instead of `loop` and `recur`:

```
(defn merge-sorted [s]
  (->> s
       (filter seq)
       (unfold
         (fn [s]
           (if (seq s)
             (let [[[mf & mn] r]
                   (reduce
                     (fn [[m r] x]
                       (if (< (first x) (first m))
                         [x (cons m r)]
                         [m (cons x r)]))
                     [(first s) ()]
                     (rest s))]
               (list mf (if mn (cons mn r) r))))))))
```

---

## UPDATE'

Impressed by the efficiency of A. Webb's solution after the edit and considering this problem interesting and relatively important, I had a look at the Wikipedia articles on [merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) and [k-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm) algorithms and at [this paper](http://www.cs.uno.edu/people/faculty/bill/k-way-merge-n-sort-ACM-SE-Regl-1993.pdf). I found out that there is plenty of room for analysis/experimentation/improvement and decided to (re)implement and test several algorithms. Here they are, packed in a map, preceded by some helper functions and followed by some functions useful for testing:

```
(require ['clojure.core.reducers :as 'reducers])

(defn mapmap [f m]
  (reduce #(update %1 %2 f) m (keys m)))

(defn unfold [f s]
  (->> s
       (list nil)
       (iterate (comp f second))
       rest
       (take-while some?)
       (map first)))

(defn foldh [f s]
  ((fn rec [v]
     (f (if (> (count v) 2)
          (let [h (quot (count v) 2)]
            (map rec [(subvec v 0 h) (subvec v h)]))
          v)))
   (vec s)))

(defn fold2 [f s]
  (loop [s s]
    (if (nnext s)
      (recur (map f (partition-all 2 s)))
      (f s))))

(def merge-sorted
  (merge
    ;direct lazy algorithms
    (mapmap
      (fn [[prepare choose insert]]
        (fn [s]
          (->> s
               (filter seq)
               prepare
               (unfold
                 (fn [s]
                   (if (seq s)
                     (let [[[xf & xn] s] (choose s)]
                       [xf (if xn (insert s xn) s)])))))))
      {:min
       [identity
        (fn [s]
          (reduce
            (fn [[x s] y]
              (if (< (first x) (first y))
                [x (cons y s)]
                [y (cons x s)]))
            [(first s) ()]
            (rest s)))
        conj]
       :sort
       [(partial sort-by first)
        (juxt first rest)
        (fn [s [xf :as x]]
          (let [[a b] (loop [a () b (seq s)]
                        (if-let [[bf & bn] b]
                          (if (< (first bf) xf)
                            (recur (cons bf a) bn)
                            [a b])
                          [a b]))]
            (into (cons x b) a)))]
       :lsort
       [(partial sort-by first)
        (juxt first rest)
        (fn [s [xf :as x]]
          ((fn rec [s]
             (lazy-seq
               (if-let [[sf] (seq s)]
                 (if (< (first sf) xf)
                   (cons sf (rec (rest s)))
                   (cons x s))
                 (list x))))
           s))]
       :heap
       [(fn [s]
          (let [h (java.util.PriorityQueue.
                    (count s)
                    #(< (first %1) (first %2)))]
            (run! #(.add h %) s)
            h))
        (fn [h] [(.poll h) h])
        (fn [h x] (.add h x) h)]})
    ;folding lazy algorithms
    (mapmap
      (letfn [(merge2 [s]
                (lazy-seq
                  (if-let [[x & s] (seq (filter seq s))]
                    (if-let [[y] s]
                      ((fn rec [x y]
                         (lazy-seq
                           (let [[[xf & xn] y]
                                 (if (< (first x) (first y))
                                   [x y]
                                   [y x])]
                             (cons xf (if xn (rec xn y) y)))))
                       x y)
                      x))))]
        (fn [fold] (partial fold merge2)))
      {:foldl #(reduce (comp %1 list) %2)
       :foldh foldh
       :fold2 fold2})
    ;folding eager algorithms
    (mapmap
      (letfn [(merge2 [s]
                (if-let [[x & s] (seq (filter seq s))]
                  (if-let [[y] s]
                    (loop [x x y y acc ()]
                      (let [[[xf & xn] y]
                            (if (< (first x) (first y))
                              [x y]
                              [y x])
                            acc (conj acc xf)]
                        (if xn
                          (recur xn y acc)
                          (into y acc))))
                    x)
                  ()))]
        (fn [fold] (partial fold merge2)))
      {:efoldp #(reducers/fold 2 (comp %1 list) (comp %1 list) (vec %2))
       :efoldh foldh
       :efold2 fold2})))

(defn gen-inp [m n]
  (->> 0
       (repeat m)
       (map
         (comp
           doall
           (partial take n)
           rest
           (partial iterate #(+ % (rand-int 100)))))
       doall))

(defn test-merge-sorted [m n & algs]
   (->> (or algs (sort (keys merge-sorted)))
        (map (juxt name merge-sorted))
        (run!
          (let [inp (gen-inp m n)]
            (fn [[id alg]]
              (println id)
              ;(java.lang.System/gc)
              (try
                (time (doall (alg inp)))
                (catch java.lang.StackOverflowError _
                  (prn "Stack overflow"))))))))
```

The direct lazy algorithms follow a common scheme parameterized by how the following are done:

- preprocessing the input
- computing one chosen sequence and the rest ones
- inserting the tail of the chosen sequence into the rest ones

`:min` is like my first solution, which calculates a minimum at each iteration.

`:sort` is like Rulle's solution, which sorts the sequences initially and makes a sorted-insertion at each iteration.

`:lsort` is like `:sort` but with lazy insertion. It can cause stack overflow because of nested lazy sequences.

`:heap` is a simple but suboptimal implementation of heap-merge using Java's `PriorityQueue`s.

The folding lazy algorithms follow a common scheme parameterized by how a `<=2`-ary merge is extended to arbitrary arities.

`:foldl` is like A. Webb's solution before the edit, which does a left folding using `reduce`. It can cause stack overflow because of nested lazy sequences.

`:foldh` is an implementation of divide-and-conquer-merge, which folds by splitting in half.

`:fold2` is like A. Webb's solution after the edit, which folds by splitting in pairs.

The folding eager algorithms follow a scheme like that of the lazy ones but using an eager `<=2`-ary merge.

`:efoldp` is a parallel implementation of divide-and-conquer-merge using `clojure.core.reducers/fold`, which does various `<=2`-ary merges concurrently and possibly in parallel, by "forking" every time it splits in half.

`:efoldh` and `:efold2` are like `:foldh` and `:fold2` but eager.

As a short remark on performance I would say that, for fast lazy merging, one of `:foldh`, `:fold2` or maybe `:heap` should be chosen. As for eager merging, depending on the hardware's parallelism ability and on the input's shape, `:efoldp` can be faster than the rest. For more information see the linked articles.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write this out explicitly, for a lazy performant version.

```
(defn merges 
  ([x] x)

  ([x y]
    (cond 
      (empty? x) y
      (empty? y) x
      (< (first x) (first y)) 
        (cons (first x) (lazy-seq (merges y (rest x))))       
     :else 
      (cons (first y) (lazy-seq (merges x (rest y))))))

   ([x y & more]
     (apply merges 
       (for [[a b] (partition-all 2 (list* x y more))]
         (merges a b)))))


(apply merges [[1 3 4 6 9 10 15]
               [2 3 6 7 8 9 10]
               [1 3 6 7 8 9 10]
               [1 2 3 4 8 9 10]])
```

Edit: This revision merges pairwise up a binary tree for depth log number of sequences, rather than the prior linear reduction.

Comment: This can lead to stack overflow (e.g. for an input of 10000 sequences) because it "stacks" a lot of lazy sequences.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but is it the stack that bears the burden or the heap/GC? Clojure will typically unwind nested lazy-seq thunks in place. Under zcaudate's benchmark with 20000/10000 parameters the heap/GC error occurs for me by simply attempting to create the `arrs` input!  But, I was a lazy programmer in handling the more-than-two case with a linear reduction. I replaced with a tree approach. This handles tens of thousands of input sequences easily, so long each isn't too long for memory to bear in total.

Comment: First of all, I think it should be clarified that, although Clojure does not use extra stack space when forcing a `LazySeq` thunk returns another such thunk, it does so when forcing a thunk entails forcing another one, which is the case in this answer. Of course, after the edit, the use of stack space is so little that it is unproblematic. It should also be stressed that the efficiency of this solution after the edit is not so much a result of the lower level implementation (explicit recursion etc.) but of the fact that the algorithm implemented has lower asymptotic time complexity.